# JavaScript - How To Detect Number As A Decimal (Including 1.0)

Tags: javascript

It feels like I am missing something obvious here.  This has been asked a number of times - and the answer usually boils down to:

```
var num = 4.5;
num % 1 === 0; // false - 4.5 is a decimal
```

But, this fails for

```
var num = 1.0; // or 2.0, 3.0, ...
num % 1 // 0
```

Unfortunately, these doesn't work either

```
num.toString() // 1
typeof num // "number"
```

I am writing a JavaScript color parsing library, and I want to process input differently if it is given as 1.0 or 1.  In my case, `1.0` really means 100% and `1` means 1.

Otherwise, both `rgb 1 1 1` and `rgb 1 255 255` will be parsed as `rgb 255 255 255` (since I am right now taking anything <= 1 to mean a ratio).

Comment: So, if there's a decimal point, it's a percentage, otherwise it's just the integer value?

Comment: I think you're out of luck since `1.0 === 1`.

Comment: Short of getting it as a string, I don't think you have any options here. JavaScript does not make any real distinction between floats and integers. I'll be following the question though, I'm interested to see if there's a potential answer.

Comment: Jonathan - yes, that is what I am hoping to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those numbers aren't actually decimals or integers.  They're all floats.  The only real difference between `1` and `1.0` is the notation that was used to create floats of equal values.

---

Edit: to help illustrate, consider:

```
1 === 1.0; // true
parseInt('1') == parseInt('1.0'); // true
parseFloat('1') === parseFloat('1.0'); // true
parseInt('1') === parseFloat('1'); // true
// etc...
```

Also, to demonstrate that they are really the same underlying data type:

```
typeof(1); // 'number'
typeof(1.0); // 'number'
```

Also, note that 'number' isn't unambiguous in JavaScript like it would be in other languages, because numbers are always floats.

---

Edit 2: One more addition, since it's relevant.  To the best of my knowledge, the only context in JavaScript in which you actually have "real and true" integers that aren't really represented as floats, is when you're doing bitwise operations.  However, in this case, the interpreter converts all the floats to integers, performs the operation, and then converts the result back to a float before control is returned.  Not totally pertinent to this question, but it helps to have a good understanding of Number handling in JS in general.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response - I have been learning a lot about how JS handles numbers from this project.  I have a feeling I'm going to need to only accept string input for "1.0" in an object.  So, `tinycolor({r: .5, g: "1.0", b: .9})`.

Comment: You could do it that way, or perhaps refactor the API to be a little more explicit.  E.g., tinyColor(/*assumes 0-255*/) and tinyColor.fromRatio(/*assumes decimals*/), etc.

Comment: Hmm that is a good thought.  My goal is to have the string parsing as robust as possible, where the 1.0 and 1 difference can be detected.  I am using this library for a colorpicker, and I want the user input to be as permissive as possible - you can type 'red', 'f00', 'ff0000', 'rgb 255 0 0', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)', 'rgb 1.0 0 0', etc.  I suppose if there needs to be another method for object input that specifically asks for ratios that could work, but I'm leaning towards just requiring a string, since it gets really weird with: `{ h:360, s: 1.0, v: 1.0 }` :)

Comment: Well if this is for user input, then I think you're golden with the string parsing, since that's how you'll actually get the user-provided value, presumably. I think it would be awkward if it was a code API, but if you're controlling things from text input and on, then string parsing seems legit.

Comment: Yeah, I will just modify my bound01() function here: https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor/blob/fbee79b712cad2a3f1405fd6301b2d65290a1f69/tinycolor.js#L515 to allow "1.0" string input.  I think I will just treat "1.0" as "100%".  This seems like the best solution, though I still wish I could get the difference between 1.0 and 1

Answer (score 3):

Let your script parse the input as string, then it will be a matter of checking if there is the point like this.

```
mystring.indexOf('.');
```

Check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/9XLLZ/) and [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/R9vgr/).

Comment: Thanks, but 1.0.toString() turns into "1"

Comment: Check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/yXQYW/2/) please. If you input a int number, it will return false, if you type 1.0 for example, it will return true, effectively checking it's a float.

Comment: You are right about that, and I will implement it like that IF the input is a string.  The tricky part is if an object is passed in, like { r: 1.0, g: 1, b: .5 }.  It seems once the variable is in memory, there is no difference between 1 and 1.0.

Comment: Once a float is in memory, the decimal part gets removed automatically if equals zero. From there on you cannot possibly know if the was an integer or a float.

Answer (score 2):

```js
Number.isInteger(4.5)
```

`Number.isInteger()` is part of the ES6 standard and not supported in IE11.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do it when parsing the string. If there's a decimal point in the *string*, treat it as percentage, otherwise it's just the integer value.

So, e.g.:

```
rgb 1 1 1   // same as #010101
rgb 1.0 1 1 // same as #ff0101
```

Since the `rgb` is there, you're parsing the string anyway. Just look for `.` in there as you're doing it.

Comment: I might need to do it that way.  I would still like to be able to handle input as an object though, since I allow both 'rgb 1 1 1' and {r: 1, g: 1.0, b: 1}

Comment: To do that, detect the `typeof` variable passed. If object, treat appropriately; if string, parse. The trick will be with the object, since the values for the attributes will be floats. As discussed in other answers, once you're in a float, you won't be able to tell if an integer was initially expressed with a decimal point or not. You might do best to *require* the user to express percentages with a % sign. This is, of course, forcing them to be strings.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  After all the responses, I think I will handle the string parsing as described, and force the object input to either be in percentages, or as a string for the special 1.0 case { r: "1.0", g: .5, b: .5 }.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as the compiler is concerned, there is no difference between 1.0 and 1, and because there is no difference, it is impossible to tell the difference between them. You should change it from 1.0 to 100 for the the percentage thing. That might fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 1;
```

and

```
var num = 1.0;
```

are the same.  You mention that you want to treat them differently when given from a user.  You will want to parse the difference when it is still a string and convert it to the appropriate number.