# Issue with input number when number has .0

Tags: javascript, input, floating-point, numbers, integer

Got issue when trying to validate the input type number.

I want to accept integers only.
Don't want to accept float (it almost works).

Got issue with number like `1.0`, `3.0`, but not with `1.1`
When doing `_.toNumber` it change `1.0` to `1` but still I want to know that user inputed the `1.0` because this is an issue. Any idea?

Comment: `1.0` is still a float number, right? But you said, you want to accept only Integers?

Comment: store the initial string (1.0) in addition to the cast number value

Comment: My input should only accept the integers, but when user use `,` then it is accepted (for browser this isn't floating indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var number = 1.0;
if(number % 1 == 0){
    //validated code
}
else{
   //invalidate
}
```

**or**

```
function isInt(n) {
  return n % 1 === 0;
}
```

If you don't know that the argument is a **integer number** , then you need two tests

```
function isInt(n){
   return Number(n) === n && n % 1 === 0;
}
```

Comment: Almost but want to accept the `"1"` and `"3"` but not `"1.0"`

Comment: so, Just get the number and convert to String and search the string includes **.(decimal)** 
`number = n.toString();`
`if(!number.includes(".")){ //codes }`

Comment: Can you please see the following link, you might get an idea.

[Link may Help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422072/javascript-how-to-detect-number-as-a-decimal-including-1-0)

Comment: Ok I did it with regex. Pattern `^([0-9])+$`

Comment: But this isn't best option because it accepts `012` but shouldn't